# span tag shows records from database but its not selectable I want its should be selectable and click after its shown on input box

Tags: java, ajax, jsp

> I gets the records from database using ajax function but ajax gives
>   results in span tag its not selectable ....i want its should
>   selectable and click after record clickble record shown in input
>   box...
>
> i was done with ajax function and external jsp file through..

**AJAX FUNCTION**

```
<script>  
var request=new XMLHttpRequest();  

function searchInfo(){  
var course_name=document.batch_form.course_name.value;  
var url="search.jsp?val="+course_name;  

try{  
request.onreadystatechange=function(){  
if(request.readyState==4){  
var val=request.responseText;  
document.getElementById('location').innerHTML=val;  
}  
}//end of function  
request.open("GET",url,true);  
request.send();  
}catch(e){alert("Unable to connect to server");}  
}  
</script>
```

**EXTERNAL JSP FILE**

```
<%  
String course_name=request.getParameter("val");  
if(course_name==null||course_name.trim().equals("")){  
out.print("<p  style='margin-left:145px;color:red;'>Please Enter Course Name...!</p>");  
}else{  
try{  

    //Connection con = Connect.createConnection();
     Connection con=null;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); //loading MySQL drivers. This differs for database servers 
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/new_database", "root", "");
    //attempting to connect to MySQL database 
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from course where course_name like '"+course_name+"%'");  
ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();  

if(!rs.isBeforeFirst()) {      
     out.println("<p>No Record Found!</p>");   
    }else{  
    out.print("<table frame='box' width='' style='min-width:377px; margin-left:140px;' >");  
    while(rs.next()){  
    out.print("<tr><td class='form-control'  style='font-size:13px;color:black;font-weight: bold;'>"+rs.getString(2)+"</td></tr>");  
//out.print(rs.getString(2));  

}  
out.print("</table>");   
}//end of else for rs.isBeforeFirst  
con.close();  
}catch(Exception e){out.print(e);}  
}//end of else  
%>
```

Comment: This here `request.open("GET",url,true);` you are saying  that operation should happen asynchronously. As you are using JSP and try to read the data immediately prefer to use the `request.open("GET",url, false);` and place the call before the `request.onreadystatechange`

Comment: sorry sir I made changes in my code still it is not working......

Comment: You want the selected value in separate input box

Comment: yes sir.........